# Play video in ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In y windows application, I am want to  play video in my application using this link `http://rubydoc.info/gems/jw_player_helper/0.0.1/file/README.markdown#` . In the `Rails 3` heading of this link.

The first two steps I have done, i.e below:
but in the 3rd step, I don't understand what he says:

1. add gem `jw_player_helper` into your `Gemfile`
2. add `<%= javascript_include_tag 'swfobject' %>` in your `html.rb`
3. now you can use  `<%= video_player(flashvars={}, attributes={}, params={}) %>` to render JW Player

Can you help me figure out what to do?

Comment: When you say "in my Windows application" - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put video in public folder, and change this :file => "/video/water_msg.flv"

Answer (score 2):

Example. hope it helps.

```
 <%= video_player({:file => "/video/pf2011.flv", :image => "/video/pf2011.jpg"}) %>
```

renders JW Player with splash screen pf2011.jpg

```
<%= video_player({:file => "/video/pf2011.flv", :image => "/video/pf2011.jpg"}, {:width => 640, :height => 480, :id => "pf2011_video"}) %>
```

renders JW Player with resolution 640x480px and id pf2011_video

```
<%= video_player({:file => "/video/pf2011.flv", :image => "/video/pf2011.jpg", :mute => true}, {:width => 640, :height => 480, :id => "pf2011_video", :onclick => "alert('clicked!');"}) %>
```

You will put this into your Html.rb so that your video post on your page..

Comment: put that code into your html.rb..can you explain me further to your problem..cause i know i can help you with this.

Comment: dont use numbers..instead of 1.flv  change it into name(letters).flv..so that the path can read it.. but if you cant solve that into your path..try to follow my new answers above

Comment: what ruby version you used? i gave all the data and knowledge i have.. that codes runs well to me.. maybe your problem is all about yours

Comment: I am using ruby '1.9.3' version.

Comment: your version is not compatible to that.. rails 2,3,4 version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56182/discussion-between-user88-and-cjnahine05).

Answer (score 0):

I want to help you with this problem ..but maybe you need to change all to this.just flow  all of these.OKAY ?
Download jwplayer from http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/download/

Put these files to the particular directory:-

app/assets/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf

vendor/assets/javascripts/jwplayer.js

vendor/assets/javascripts/jwplayer.html5.js

Then add these line in application.js

```
//= require jwplayer
//= require jwplayer.html5
```

On the page where you are playing video, add these lines

```
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="YOUR_JWPLAYER_KEY";</script>
  <div id="video">Loading the player ...</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("video").setup({
  flashplayer: "<%=asset_path('jwplayer.flash.swf')%>",
  file: "<%= file_path %>",
  height: 360,
  width: 640,
  analytics: {
    enabled: false,
    cookies: false
  }
});
</script>
```

https://account.longtailvideo.com/#/account from where you can get your Self-Hosted Player License Key (YOUR_JWPLAYER_KEY) in signing up from Get Your License Key portion.

Take a look https://github.com/shamsulsham89/jwplayer-rails3.2

Please test it first on Chrome Version 30

Comment: getting error `C:/Sites/VideoResume/app/views/static_pages/viewresume.html.erb:25: unknown regexp options - vd` at this line `file: "<%= /assets/video/water_msg.flv %>",`